# Inserting items on default menus with extension org.eclipse.plugin.menus

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add some options on the menu programatically, I already found out how to add a menu after the menu "Window", but I want to add a option inside the default menu (more specifically, add my perspective inside Window>Open Perspective).

I dont know what is the correct LocationURL.

Actually, my extension point is configured like that:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=window">
     <menu
           icon="icons/enmac.jpg"
           id="enmac"
           label="EnMac">
        <command
              commandId="EnMac.openPerspective"
              icon="icons/enmac.jpg"
              label="Open Perspective"
              style="push"
              tooltip="open">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can often use the plug-in spy tool in Eclipse to find menu URI's. This can be accessed by ALT+SHIFT+F2 (at least on Windows platforms) then clicking on an appropriate menu item.

However in this case it sounds like you are really just trying to add your perspective to the default perspectives menu. In this case you should register your perspective class using the *org.eclipse.ui.perspectives* extension point. See [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html) for more details.